# Is it necessary to create an array before pushing elements into it?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

Need to run a query on a MySQL database to find a specific set of records. Then create a while loop to send records to a web service. Code is working but I have found a few issues.

Is it necessary to set an additional array even if `mysqli_fetch_assoc` is used to store the rows? The syntax `$array = array();` and `$array[] = $row;` present in my code does not always return all rows for larger result sets but when omitting those it returns all of the rows it should.

Can someone please explain this to me? I found this sample on another forum and just want to understand why the row was set as an array again if `mysqli_fetch_assoc` is already doing this? Or what is the correct way of ensuring my query returns every single row and then sends to the web service in the while loop

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT *
FROM `table`.`list`
WHERE `list`.`last_local_call_time` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 12 HOUR)
AND `list`.`list_id` = '5005'
AND `list`.`vendor_lead_code` = 'test'");

// set array

$array = array();

// look through query

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){

  // add each row returned into an array

  $array[] = $row;

//payload

  $row['phone_number'] = preg_replace('/^27/', '0', $row['phone_number']);
  $data_json = '{
    "LeadDetails": [
        {
            "Attribute": "Phone",
            "Value": "'.$row['phone_number'].'"
        },
        {
            "Attribute": "SearchBy",
            "Value": "Phone"
        }
    ],
    "Activity": {
    "ActivityEvent": 201,
    "Fields": [
        {
            "SchemaName": "Status",
            "Value": "'.$row['status'].'"
        }
    ]
}

//send payload to API

  $curl_url = 'https://test.api.com';
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $curl_url);             
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST"); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);                                                
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(  
      'Content-Type: application/json',                                                                          
      'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json))                                                                       
  ); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0); 
  $curl_result = curl_exec($ch);
  $curl_info = curl_getinfo($ch);
echo $curl_result;
//error checking
if (curl_error($ch)) {
$error_msg = curl_error($ch);
//echo $error_msg;
}
}';
```

Comment: This question is off topic. *Obviously*, the number of results is not related to the way you are fetching them. and whether you define an array or not is not related as well. Your problem lies elsewhere. Instead of some guess you must ask a question regarding the actual problem you have: not all rows are returned. You must explain in detail how does it look when "not all rows are returned" and why do you think it is not all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes an array is declared so it can be used outside the scope. In this case the scope is the while loop. However in this example you could just use $row and remove the array.

Another reason to declare an array is to make clear what you're retrieving from the database, so instead of $array something like $phoneNumbers.

Comment: PHP has only function scope. Your answer is a little bit misleading.

Comment: Why is it misleading?